# Get row index of custom cell in UITableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, ios5

I'm developing an ipad app. I have a UITableview in the app. The UITableview is created programatically with one label and textview as its subview. There can be a max of five rows in tableview. At a time 2 rows are displayed to the user. In runtime, its require to enter some text in the textview & save it in the local sqlite db. I have implemented the textViewDidBeginEditing and textViewDidEndEditing delegates in the code. In the textViewDidEndEditing delegate, Im trying to add/replace the text(entered in textview) in an NSMUtable array. For that the rowindex of the textview for which I enter the text is required. So that i can add/replace the respective row index in the array.

Please let me know how to get the row index of the text view.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your `TextView` will be contained within some kind of cell. Once you have found this cell, you can ask the table for the index. Navigate from your `TextView` up the view hierarchy to find the cell. For example:

```
TextView* textView = // your textView;
UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)[textView superview];
UITableView* table = (UITableView *)[cell superview];
NSIndexPath* pathOfTheCell = [table indexPathForCell:cell];
NSInteger rowOfTheCell = [pathOfTheCell row];
NSLog(@"rowofthecell %d", rowOfTheCell);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is working in some scenarios and in other scenarios it gives inappropriate row index. Like if i navigate from row 0 to row 5 then to row 4 then to row 0, in the textviewDidEndediting it shows the index path.row as 0 whereas it should show 3 which is the index of the row i edited.

Answer (score 7):

its really Simple, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. just tag your `textView` like

```
cell.txtView.tag = indexPath.row;
```

in textView Delegate method find the row using following code (`textViewDidBeginEditing`)

```
int row = textView.tag;
```

Comment: Be careful if you're adding or removing cells from the tableView after setting this tag - the order will change, leaving tags with the wrong values.

Answer (score 3):

In **Swift** running on **iOS 8.4**:

```
@IBAction func signInUpBigButtonPressed(sender: SignInUpMenuTableViewControllerBigButton) {
    // We set the self.indexCellContainingButtonClicked with the cell number selected.
    var parentCell: UIView! = sender
    do {
        parentCell = parentCell.superview!
    } while !(parentCell is UITableViewCell)
    let cell = parentCell as! UITableViewCell
    self.indexCellContainingButtonClicked = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!.row
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a more elegant way to accomplish what you asked

```
CGPoint senderPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:senderPosition];
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a much better solution than the rest in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Running IOS 8.3 found and implemented this within a textViewDidEndEditing
method; works well!

```
UIView *parentCell = sender
while (![parentCell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {   // iOS 7 onwards the table cell hierachy has changed.
    parentCell = parentCell.superview;
}

UIView *parentView = parentCell.superview;

while (![parentView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {   // iOS 7 onwards the table cell hierachy has changed.
    parentView = parentView.superview;
}


UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)parentView;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)parentCell];

NSLog(@"indexPath = %@", indexPath);
```