# Detect the index of CustomCell Item clicked on TableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, custom-cell

I have a custom cell where I have two textfields and one label. I have added a `TapGestuRecognizer` to capture user tap event on the label. However, I wonder how could I able to detect the index of CustomCell where label selected?

```
var tapGesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer (Tap);
myLabel.AddGestureRecognizer (tapGesture);
myLabel.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

public void Tap(UITapGestureRecognizer r) 
{
    var vc = new myViewController (this);
    var nc = new NavigationController (vc);
    nc.PreferredContentSize = new System.Drawing.SizeF (200, 300);
    popupoverController = new UIPopoverController (nc);
    popupoverController.PresentFromRect (myLabel.Bounds, myLabel, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, true);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13723853/826716

Answer (score 0):

Convert point of touch (or CGPointZero, it really doesn't matter) from your label (you can obtain it from your tap recognizer - it has `view` property) to table view coordinates with

```
func convertPoint(_ point: CGPoint, toView view: UIView?) -> CGPoint
```

Alternatively, you can use method of UITapGestureRecognizer for this

```
func locationInView(_ view: UIView?) -> CGPoint
```

And then find the indexPath of cell at that point

```
func indexPathForRowAtPoint(_ point: CGPoint) -> NSIndexPath?
```

Docs: [Converting Between View Coordinate Systems](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertPoint:toView:).

Answer (score 0):

If the gesture recognizer belongs to the table view cell, add an indexPath property to your table view cell subclass :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *indexPath;
```

then set it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method before returning the cell.

Then handle the touch in the table view cell class, based on the `self.indexPath` property.

In the same way, you can also add a pointer to the "parent" table view controller (`weak` this time, so as not to create circular references), then you can access its public properties like the array you're populating your table view with.