# How to know the indexPath of the cell SWIFT

Tags: swift, uibutton, tableview, cell

I have a custom `tableview`. And it contains a `button`. And the question is how to know which button was tapped? From which `indexPath.row`. I tried to do it in didSelectRowAt but, I am not selecting any cell, I am just pressing `button`. I need it in SWIFT

Comment: please look at the [question which already answered yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802707/detecting-which-uibutton-was-pressed-in-a-uitableview), though many are in ObjC they actually can easily be converted to Swift. If you need example codes you may also look at my answer I've added to that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will give you Button tag and also know which button is tapped. Right this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath UITableView DataSource Delegate Method.

```
    cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    func btnTapped(_ sender : UIButton) {
       print(sender.tag)
    }
```

Comment: could you tell please what btn is?

Comment: Its is your UIButton.

Comment: it should be action or outlet?

Comment: So replace btn with btnTapped.

Comment: yeah it works) Thank you dude

Comment: Your Welcome bro.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton * btn = /* your button */;
UITableViewCell * cellContainingBtn = (UITableViewCell*)[btn superview];
UITableView * tbl = (UITableView *)[cellContainingBtn superview];
NSIndexPath * cellIndexPath = [tbl indexPathForCell:cellContainingBtn];
NSInteger index = [cellIndexPath row];
```

Answered here:
[Get row index of custom cell in UITableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723785/get-row-index-of-custom-cell-in-uitableview)

As an easy alternative, you could assign the indexPath.row of cell to the button's accessibilityLabel or accessibilityHint etc.